# Multiple layouts, one activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to create an activity that contains 5 "**FrameLayout**" like the picture below.
3 equal FrameLayout in the first row and 2 FrameLayout in the second row.

[image]

I did it using Linear layouts but I got a warning that **nested weights are bad**. So is there an other way to make it.

Fragments should be streched on the screen **without using values like (100dp).**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00bbff" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="1" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#bb00ff" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="2" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#00ff00" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="3" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                 android:background="#bbff00">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="4" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="#ffbb00" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="5" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It uses nested LinearLayout with weights as well, thus it's no different from OP's solution.

Comment: @aga I did not get `nested weights are bad` warning.

Comment: @Aniruddha the solution didn't fill the height (its wrapped)

Comment: @MedBesbes You please adjust the height according to your need. I just tried to help you with the skeleton code of layout.

Comment: @Aniruddha If you can Edit your post, it will be very helpfull.

Comment: @MedBesbes I changed height of FrameLayouts to 100dp. You can set it to whatever you want.

Comment: It's not interesting to put values (100dp)

Answer (score 0):

you cal also use the two table layout..
like

```
<TableLayout android:weight='1'>
   <TableRow>
      <Linear> 
        <FrameLayout /> <FrameLayout /> <FrameLayout /> 
      </Linear>
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout android:weight='1'>
   <TableRow>
      <Linear> 
        <FrameLayout /> <FrameLayout/>
      </Linear>
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

its rough layout . i hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::Hope its useful for you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00bbff"
              >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />
        </FrameLayout>


        <View  android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#bb00ff" 
           >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="2" 
                />
        </FrameLayout>

          <View  android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00" 
           >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="3" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#bbff00" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="4" />
        </FrameLayout>

         <View  android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffbb00" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="5" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  see image below  ![image][1]

See This code
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"> 
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"/>
    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"/>
    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout> 
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"/>
    </LinearLayout> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```